# Use Google Guice's AssistedInject with JAXB

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jaxb, guice

In one of my project I use Guice to do dependency injection. One of the classes in my model uses Guice's `AssistedInject` to inject some sort of a manager that implements a certain interface:

```
public final class A_Class {
    private final String string;
    private final ManagerInterface interface;

    @Inject
    public A_Class(@Assisted String string, ManagerInterface interface) {
        ...
    }

    // getters, equals, hashCode, toString, etc.
}
```

Of course I have one of those factory-interfaces in order to create an instance of `A_Class` by only giving a `String`:

```
public interface A_Factory {

    A_Class create(String s);
}
```

One of the next steps in this project is to store instances of `A_Class` as XML and also create instances by reading an XML-file. For that part I want to use the JAXB-library. As discussed in (among others) [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387296/jaxb-and-constructors), you can't use `A_Class` in the XML-process, because it doesn't have an empty constructor. What I do to that is discussed in the thread I just mentioned. I make the following class:

```
public class A_Class_Adaptee {

    private String s;

    @XmlElement
    public String getS() {
        return this.s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

as well as a sub-class of JAXB's `XmlAdapter`, called `A_Class_Adapter`. Now here comes the problem: in order to implement its `unmarshal()`-method, I need to have access to the factory-interface that creates an instance of `A_Class`. But since `A_Class_Adapter` can't have a constructor with parameters, I can't inject that factory-interface. To be clear, what I basicly want is something like this:

```
public class A_Class_Adapter extends XmlAdapter<A_Class_Adaptee, A_Class> {

    @Override
    public A_Class unmarshal(A_Class_Adaptee adaptee) {
        return factory.create(adaptee.getS());
    }

    @Override
    public A_Class_Adaptee marshal(A_Class aClass) {
        A_Class_Adaptee adaptee = new A_Class_Adaptee();
        adaptee.setS(aClass.getS());
        return adaptee;
    }
}
```

but I have no idea how to inject the `factory`-interface, which is created by Guice.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Or am I thinking in the wrong direction and is there another way to achieve my goal of reading XML? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is another way. Restructure your classes in such way so data classes (JAXB-annotated ones) do not have any dependencies; if they do have dependencies, it is very likely that it is a violation of single responsibility principle. This way you won't need assisted inject or any other hacks.

Comment: I disagree on that. This is not a violation of single responsibility, because that interface takes care of some other responsibility, which was in the class itself before. Again, what I want is use some sort of Guice command to create the instance of my class. Unfortunately nobody seems to have a reasonable solution.

Comment: it is a violation since this class does two things - it carries data and also does something using its dependency. When you structure your program in such way so data classes are separate from behavior classes, you get more testable solutions which are easily implemented using dependency injection. The most you can get in your case (if you do not want to perform refactoring) is [on-demand injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections#On-demand_Injection), but it is not idiomatic usage of guice and is not recommended,