# Deserialize final object reference with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following code. I would like to be able to construct the object created in the main method from an XML file. I was thinking about a structure in the form `<Main><CustomModel/></Main>`. Is this possible with JAXB and how can I achieve something like this?

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Main {   
    private final Model model;

    public Main(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main(new CustomModel());
    }
}

interface Model {};

class CustomModel implements Model {
    @XMLElement String test = "1234";
};
```

Comment: Check the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387296/jaxb-and-constructors

Comment: hmm.. this still looks quite impossible though... Because it would require a Builder and Adapter for each subclass of the Interface, and even then you're not able to let JAXB find out which implementation for the interface should be deserialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Simple XML Serialization, because they handle interfaces and constructor parameters for setting final variables differently. See http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#list . I'm still not sure if this is possible with JAXB.